# candidate would match and infer 'T' = '[U]' if '[U]' conformed to 'Foo'

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

If code like this, error shows and complier can't infer `T = [U]`.

```
protocol Foo { }

protocol Bar {
    associatedtype T: Foo
    var type: T { get }
}

struct Baz<U: Foo> {
    let type: [U]
}

extension Baz: Bar { }

/* error message
error: Demo.playground:14:1: error: type 'Baz<U>' does not conform to protocol 'Bar'
extension Baz: Bar { }
^

Demo.playground:6:20: note: unable to infer associated type 'T' for protocol 'Bar'
    associatedtype T: Foo
                   ^

Demo.playground:11:9: note: candidate would match and infer 'T' = '[U]' if '[U]' conformed to 'Foo'
    let type: [U]
        ^
*/
```

But Replace `Foo` with `Decodable`, complier can infer `T = [U]`, why?

```
// protocol Foo { }

protocol Bar {
    associatedtype T: Decodable
    var type: T { get }
}

struct Baz<U: Decodable> {
    let type: [U]
}

extension Baz: Bar { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array` has this extension:

```swift
extension Array: Encodable where Element: Encodable …
```

Do the same.

```swift
extension Array: Foo where Element: Foo { }
```

Comment: hey @Jessy, if `Foo` has some properties, the Array will must have those properties too, but Array shouldn't have. What should I do?

Comment: Consider whether there's actually some protocol that the two things have in common. Make a new one if so, that represents that. This seems like a new question; feel free to link to another question that you'll write.